# Hotkey for "paste shortcut" in windows 7 explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, hotkeys

In folder view, we right click on a file and copy it and then somewhere else, we right click and say "paste shortcut"

I could not find a hotkey combination for "paste shortcut".

Google search for "paste shortcut" etc is pretty much useless. It gives me shortcuts for "paste"

Answer (score 4):

Nice question. Vote up for making everyone notice about this. As [Microsoft Site](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts) shows there is no shortcut for this. You can only create/delete a shortcut follow the steps

To create a shortcut

1. Open the location containing the item that you want to create a shortcut to.
2. Right-click the item, and then click Create shortcut. The new shortcut appears in the same location as the original item.
3. Drag the new shortcut to the desired location.

[image]

To delete a shortcut

1. Right-click the shortcut that you want to delete, click Delete, and
   then click Yes. Administrator permission required If you're prompted
   for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
   provide confirmation.

Comment: It will be good to enter the content of the link and give the link in reference and you will get the upvotes :)

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of research I have found out how to do it.Suppose you have two folders: one containing the files and another folder where you want to create the shortcut for the files. Open both windows side by side [ to do that right click windows taskbar and click show windows side by side]. **Then you have do three things simultaneously** in the correct order:select the file ,drag the file to the folder you want to create shortcut **but do not do not drop it[release left mouse button] yet** , hold ctrl+shift . Now drop it[release left mouse button] Voila shortcut is created . At first it may seem tedious but it is undeniable that it speeds creating shortcuts to a large extent.

**Reference**:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449

Comment: Looks interesting. Let me see if I can get to automate via autohotkey, that may serve the original purpose.

Answer (score 3):

To paste a shortcut using keyboard only, after having copied the file using Ctrl+C,

1. open the context menu in the target folder (keyboard focus on the file explorer's right-hand pane), either

   - using the [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) (usually located to the left of the right-hand Ctrl key),

   or, if your keyboard doesn't have a menu key,

   - using Shift+F10,

   and then
2. press "S" to select the "Paste s̲hortcut" menu entry, and possibly *Return* if the context menu contains other menu entries with the same assess key.

In short, it's *Menu*-*S*, possibly followed by *Return*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy(Ctrl+c)/Right click->*Copy*  the item you want to copy
2. Open the file/folder you want to paste the short cut
3. Click *Right mouse button* then press *S* key

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Open your actual folder where the file is and the destination folder.
- Step 2: Click and hold your file along with Alt button and release on the destination folder.
- Step 3: Congratulations! You have created a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Right click and then press S, it'll create a short cut :). Hope it helps.