# Is there a keyboard shortcut to create shortcut in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

After selecting some files/folders in Explorer, I can right-click them and choose `Create shortcut`, is there a keyboard shortcut to do so?

Comment: Likely there is no hotkey for the action you described. Related http://superuser.com/q/466894/493903

Answer (score 4):

Yes

1. Mark folders/items you want to create Shortcut to/for
2. Press and hold the [Alt] key
3. Left klick mouse and Drag the selected folders/items to a "free space" and release Mouse button
4. now you have created shortcuts - copy and handle them as you like

Comment: "mouse" isn't a keyboard shortcut

Comment: Knowing that Windows is just... Windows, I think your answer is pretty useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To start creating a New Shortcut (where you will have to type or paste the desired file path location) in Windows Explorer, use the following keyboard commands:

1.) ALT + H

2.) W

3.) S

This will use the ALT command with 'H' to go to Windows Explorer > Home, then continuing on by pressing 'W' will select the menu for new items, then continuing on by pressing 'S' will finalize the command by creating a New Shortcut, and opening the dialog window for you to specify the file path location for this New Shortcut in your current folder in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with just the keyboard. Look at your keyboard, there is a key between the right ctrl and right alt. That is the menu key. When you select a file and press the menu key it works as the right mouse button and shows the option menu. Now you can just press S key to create shortcut.

Comment: Not all keyboards are as you describe. I have a laptop where Right Alt and Right Ctrl are adjacent.  My Right Ctrl doubles as the Menu key; I have to press (Fn)+(Right Ctrl).

Answer (score 0):

This maybe overkill but it is a useful tool, you can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com)

The following will map <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to create the shortcut (meaning press those keyboard keys together and it will create your shortcut).

```
^!s::
Click right
Send s::
return
```

So simply choose any file or folder, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and it will paste the shortcut for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct keyboard shortcut. However, if you hold down `ALT` while dragging the object to the location you want the shortcut. This will create a short cut instead of moving/copying the file/folder to the new location.