# paste hard link to file on clipboard into focused folder using keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, hardlink

I would like to copy a file to the clipboard, then highlight a desired destination folder in Windows File Explorer, then press a keyboard shortcut to paste a hard link to that file into that destination folder.  (Ideally I'd like to be able with a single keypress to paste multiple hard links to multiple clipboard files to multiple folder destinations.)  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In other words, the same thing as right-clicking the desination folder and choosing Paste as Shortcut?  Have a look at this answer - https://superuser.com/a/1468459/2156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the
[Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html),
like this :

- Install the Link Shell Extension
- In the source folder, right-click the file and select "Pick Link Source"
- Right-click within the target folder and select *Drop As > Hardlink*.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[HardLink Shell Extension: Create Hardlinks, Symbolic Links, Junctions, Volume Mountpoints](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hardlink-shell-extension-create-symbolic-links).

Comment: Thank you.  I do use Link Shell Extension this way.  Unfortunately the Drop As option disappears after a single drop; you can't use it to drop a hard link in one folder, then another, unless you first repeat the Pick Link Source.  Also the Drop As option disappears if multiple destination folders are highlighted.  And really I'd like the option to use a shortcut key instead of getting into the context menu, which is a more general problem.  Still I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Jim I think your question was very good as is, and this answer should have been upvoted, but not accepted. It is next to impossible to find information regarding this on the internet otherwise :(